# Sum of squares divided by Variance asymptotic distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, convergence, chi-squared-distribution

Consider $X_i$ i.i.d. with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$.

I am aware that if $X_i$ is normally distributed then $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2/\sigma^2 \sim \chi^2_n$.

My question is, if $X_i$ has some other distribution, can it be shown (presumably in some manner appealing to the central limit theorem) that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2/\sigma^2  \rightarrow^d \chi^2_n$$

where $\rightarrow^d$ denotes convergence in distribution?

EDIT:
As $n\rightarrow \infty$, $\chi^2_n$ is asymptotically equivalent to $N(n,2n)$.

By the central limit theorem, $$\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2/\sigma^2 \rightarrow N\left(n,\frac{E[x_i^4]-\sigma^4}{\sigma^4}\right)$$

Thus, if $E[x_i^4]=3\sigma^4$ then, as $n\rightarrow \infty$, both $\chi^2_n$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2/\sigma^2 $ have distribution $N(n,2n)$.

My question is, is this result asymptotically equivalent even if excess kurtosis is nonzero?

Comment: When $E[X_i^4]\lt\infty,$ the CLT applies to the sequence of random variables $(X_i^2)$ and asserts that $1/n$ times the sum of the $X_i^2-\sigma^2$ is asymptotically *Normal.* Are you therefore implicitly supposing $E[X_i^4]=\infty$?

Comment: I think you mean < $\infty$, but yes.

Comment: No, I didn't err: I have pointed out that your question is immediately resolved when the fourth moment is finite (and effectively answered in most of our threads about the Central Limit Theorem), so that leaves only the alternative to consider.

Comment: Okay, I apologize for misunderstanding. This is clearly obvious to you, but not me. Could you provide me a link that gives me the understanding you have?

Comment: I see this:
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i^2 - \sigma^2}{\sqrt{E[x^4]-\sigma^4}} \rightarrow N(0, 1)$

Thus, $ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i^2}{\sigma^2} \sim N(n, n\frac{E[x^4]-\sigma^4}{\sigma^4})$

I feel like this somehow involves assuming that there is no excess kurtosis in $X$. That is what I am missing.

Comment: Apply the CLT to the sequence of random variables $X_i^2$ and notice that the variance of $X_i^2$ is finite if and only if the expectation of $(X_i^2)^2=X_i^4$ is finite.  The kurtosis of $X_i,$ then, determines the variance of the limiting Normal distribution, but it doesn't change the fact that it's Normal.

Comment: Yes, I know that, my point is that a chi squared with n degrees of freedom is asymptotically $N(n,2n)$. What I am seeing is that $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i^2}{\sigma^2}$ is asymptotically $N(n,n \frac{E[x^4]-\sigma^4}{\sigma^4})$. 
Thus, we need $E[x^4] = 3\sigma^4$ for these to be the same. Or can we ignore it asymptotically because $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Your $X_i^2$ will not have chi-squared distributions unless the $X_i$ are Normal, so those observations are relevant (but moot) only in that specific case.

Comment: I don't think we're having the same conversation, but I sincerely appreciate your messages and help.

Comment: I have been relying explicitly on what you write in your question.  That's the only thing we have to go on!  Let's consider your title, for instance: *unless you specify a degree of freedom parameter,* then "asymptotically chi-squared" is a meaningless phrase (or, at the least, needs a careful definition that extends the standard meaning of "asymptotically").  That might be a good start, then: just what value for the df would you propose to be the answer?

Comment: I have edited the title and added an "Edit" portion in the question. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: This may revolve around what you understand "asymptotically equivalent" to mean.  In your edit you point out that asymptotically, certain sequences of chi-squared distributions become Normal.  This means you can approximate one arbitrarily closely by the other if you go far enough out in the sequence.  "Approximate" is a symmetric relation. This *seems* to be what you mean by "this result asymptotically equivalent," leaving nothing to show. What we need here is the clearest possible statement from you concerning what you understand these asymptotic statements to mean.

Comment: So the answer to my question is "Yes" ?

Comment: I can't say, because it isn't clear what your understanding of "asymptotically equivalent" is.

Comment: I can't tell if you are being extremely precise or trying to incite frustration in me. I think it's the former though, and I appreciate your help. You wrote "This means you can approximate one arbitrarily closely by the other if you go far enough out in the sequence." This is indeed what I mean.

Comment: Due to all the misunderstandings and misinformation on this subject out there, it's crucial to be precise.  I have learned this over time by reading most of the questions and answers here on CV related to this topic (of which there are many hundreds).  If I were trying to be annoying I would have closed your question as being unclear ;-).  It remains open for anyone to chime in with a comment or even an answer.